# What are the probabilities for a tournament based selection in a genetic algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic, tournament

So I have to calculate the probability of a "x" rank individual from an "N" population to win a tournament of 2 in order to solve this problem:

Given 206 individuals, what is the probability of a rank 79 individual to survive a tournament of 2 if only one tournament has taken place so far.

So I thought basically the probability of not being selected for tournament multiplied with the probability of winning if selected.

So it would be (205/206) * (1/206) * probability to win if selected.

Is my logic correct? If yes what would the probability of winning if selected be?